# Difference between table and datasets API in arrow

Tags: pyspark, dataset, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

From the documentation, I understand that arrow provides the `datasets` API to deal with the bigger data than memory. Both have the capability for the automatic predicate/projection pushdown features (which makes it deal with greater than in-memory data anyways as it brings just what is needed), and read partitioned files. `table` API is shipped with lot of compute functions, but not for `datasets`.

But I am trying to understand the real difference between working with datasets and table API. `datasets` can read multiple files while `table` can't. But that's all? Also, if there is no big difference, why is it rising as 2 separate entities, `tables` and `datasets`, or in the future, will these both be merged to a unified element?